# bootstrap 4 remove make-row and make-col via scss, css

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, mixins

After applying the mixins make-row and make-col in scss files is there a way to remove theme via the scss files too?

ie

```
.contentType {
@include make-row();
&.no-row {
  @include kill-row();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the placement/name of classes on the elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the placement/name of classes on the elements then:

```
.contentType {
    &.row {
        @include make-row();
    }
}
```

is essentially the same as applying to all and then removing using a class (and less generated CSS). Sass cannot automatically un-apply all styles from a mixin, you would need to specifically target each style in your `kill-row` mixin and reset to the default.